# Change Focus of dataGridView cell in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the dataGridview in c# for Purchase order entry. I want to change the cell Focus from **ItemId** to **NoofQty** when I press Enter key after selecting ItemId. Then again press Enter key go to next row **ItemId**.

Which dataGridview event is suitable for this? Could you please anyone help me..
I have tried as far as I can as below
[image]

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(e.ColumnIndex==0)// ItemId
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Selected= true;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value="1";
                //I want to edit this cell value
            }
            else if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)// ItemId
            {
                //goto next row and cell is ItemId
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataGridViewRow selectedRow = myGridView.Rows[rowToSelect];
selectedRow.Selected = true;
selectedRow.Cells[columnToSelect].Selected = true;
```

OR

```
myGridView.CurrentCell = myGridView.Rows[index].Cells[4];
myGridView.BeginEdit(true);
```

Comment: Thanks.. But not working.. because I could not edit that cell value

Comment: why? what is the issue?

Comment: Currently I put your code inside **dataGridView1_CellEndEdit** event. my issue is when i press Enter key from e.columnIndex=0, then goto columnIndex 4 of the same row.

Comment: Second set of code works now. 'myGridView.CurrentCell = myGridView.Rows[index].Cells[4];
myGridView.BeginEdit(true);' But selection is showed on next Row from currently I'm editing row.

Comment: Below that you will find a Correct sign..that you have to click..to accept it as a solution

Comment: Yes I Done... Sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow thats why Delay to understand your comment...

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[0];          
        cmb.Name = "cmb";
        cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
        int no = 1001;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            no++;
            cmb.Items.Add(no.ToString());
        }            
        dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(e.ColumnIndex==0)// ItemId
            {

                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4];
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "1";
                dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);                    
            }
            else if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)// NoofQty
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex+1].Cells[0];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This code works fine as per @Pranav-BitWiser Guidance ...